# How to perform merge when multiple lines are empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say we have a dataframe1 that looks like

```
tag     random
English abc
French  xyz
Chinese poi
```

and dataframe2 looks like this

```
language  translation data
English   hello       5
          hi          3
          hey         1
Chinese   nihao       4
          xyz         0
Dutch     oy          9
French    bonjour     7
```

I would like to achieve a dataframe that looks like this:

```
output

tag      translation data
English  hello       5
Chinese  nihao       4
French   bonjour     7
```

I understand that I need to do something like

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='tag', right_on='language')
```

but I am getting a bunch of errors when I do this..

Comment: Start by doing `df2.groupby('Language').agg({'translation': 'first', 'data': 'first'})`.  Does that help?  If you have errors, post them.

Comment: Hi - ok, so I did the groupby... issue is, there are way more languages than tags.. I am getting this error `ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` after running this line   `merged_2014_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='tag')`

Comment: your example dataframe merges fine with `pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='tag', right_on='language')`

Comment: I am getting this error: `ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Comment: @sgerbhctim that error indicates that you are trying to merge on a `Series` and not a `dataframe` make sure both are dataframes by doing `type(df)` you will probably need to use `.to_frame()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The df2 is a series and not a dataframe, group it by level 0 of multi index, select first row and reset the index to convert the series to dataframe. Now use merge.

```
df1[['tag']].merge(df2.groupby(level=0).head(1).reset_index(),\
left_on = 'tag', right_on = 'language', how = 'left').drop('language', axis = 1)

    tag     translation data
0   English hello       5
1   French  bonjour     7
2   Chinese nihao       4
```